# JasperReports: list inside subdataset, how?

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have a JR report that has a subdataset:

```xml
<subDataset name="dataset4">
    <parameter name="collateralizedLimitsAndExposureList" class="java.lang.List" isForPrompting="false"/>
    <field name="exposureList" class="java.util.List"/>
    <field name="limit" class="java.lang.Object"/>
</subDataset>
```

I use a list component to iterate over this dataset4.
The main list has 4 elements now that displayed correctly. But every list item contains this ***exposureList*** that has many elements. 
I want to display that too but don't know how to iterate on the second list.

```xml
        <componentElement>
            <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="62" width="495" height="30"/>
            <jr:list xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd" printOrder="Vertical">
                <datasetRun subDataset="dataset4">
                    <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($P{exposureList})]]></dataSourceExpression>
                </datasetRun>
                <jr:listContents height="30" width="495">
                    <frame>
                        <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="0" width="495" height="30"/>
                        <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                            <reportElement style="normal_field_bold" x="5" y="0" width="50" height="10"/>
                            <textElement>
                                <font size="6" isBold="true"/>
                            </textElement>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{limit}.getLimitSymbol()]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                            <reportElement style="normal_field_bold" x="420" y="2" width="70" height="10"/>
                            <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                                <font size="6" isBold="true"/>
                            </textElement>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{limit}.getAvailableLimit()]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                            <reportElement style="normal_field" x="5" y="16" width="58" height="10"/>
                            <textElement>
                                <font size="6"/>
                            </textElement>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{exposureList}.get(0).getExternalReferenceDisplayString()]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                            <reportElement style="normal_field" x="63" y="16" width="70" height="10"/>
                            <textElement>
                                <font size="6"/>
                            </textElement>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{exposureList}.get(0).getObj()]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                            <reportElement style="normal_field" x="154" y="16" width="50" height="10"/>
                            <textElement>
                                <font size="6"/>
                            </textElement>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{exposureList}.get(0).getCcy()]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                            <reportElement style="normal_field" x="205" y="16" width="70" height="10"/>
                            <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                                <font size="6"/>
                            </textElement>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{exposureList}.get(0).getNrv()]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                            <reportElement style="normal_field" x="276" y="16" width="70" height="10"/>
                            <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                                <font size="6"/>
                            </textElement>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{exposureList}.get(0).getExp()]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                            <reportElement style="normal_field_bold" x="347" y="2" width="70" height="10"/>
                            <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                                <font size="6" isBold="true"/>
                            </textElement>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{limit}.getIssuedLimit()]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                            <reportElement style="normal_field" x="154" y="2" width="50" height="10"/>
                            <textElement>
                                <font size="6"/>
                            </textElement>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{limit}.getCcy()]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </frame>
                </jr:listContents>
            </jr:list>
        </componentElement>
```

So in this way I have a list with 4 elements and the first element from the sublist.

1. Is there any built-in variable in *JasperReports* that I can use in list's get method?
2. I know that this way it's only iterate on the main list. By the way, how can I do a second list?

Comment: Is it possible to put subreport element inside a list-component?

Comment: More-or-less working now.. Only one question. Is there any built-in variable that can be used in the List's get method? Like exposureList.get($somevariable) that increments inside the list component?

Comment: If you have this working would you mine posting an answer to your question and marking it accepted. I would be interested in seeing how you accomplished this.